# importing tables in phpmydatabase

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, upload

whole day i've been searching for an answer and managed to find a couple of leads but nothing conclusive and exactly the same so i would like to ask this question here (i'll put down all of my information for the sake of it):

i need to import one database created in phpmyadmin v5.7.x, created on linux hosting account carrying cpanel to a windows hosting account with plesk 12.0.x that has phpmyadmin v5.4.x

for now i didn't find an answer how to resize upload size for database importing (currently it's set up 2mb) for windows hosting account (mine database has 6mb). i've managed to find information that i need to change ".user.ini" file and to add specific lines but that didn't worked out, so, i've tried to upload parts of databases, table by table. 
when i try to import first table i get this error:

```
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

MySQL said: Documentation
1046 - No database selected
```

Does the problem lies in this default charset and how can i change this? i've read on this site that that's probably why. how can i and where change this? during import or export or somewhere on general settings?

i've also read that that's because the phpmyadmin's on linux and on windows aren't the same versions. Could this also be why?

if it's because the versions are not the same, is there anything i can do about it?

also, hosting of both sites is godaddy.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Trust the error message and USE database; of choice

Answer (score 0):

The current phpMyAdmin version is 4.8.3, so whatever is telling you versions 5.7 and 5.4 is incorrect. I considered that those are instead your MySQL versions, but I don't think 5.4 was ever a stable release, so that seems unlikely as well.

Anyway, P.Salmon is right, your SQL file has not specified the database to use. As a result, when you're importing in phpMyAdmin, don't do it from the main page. Instead, create the database to which you're importing, navigate to that database from the left side navigation pane, and then use the "Import" button from within the database.